# Unable to load configuration error when trying Struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, netbeans-6.9

I face a problem that when I create the web project , web.xml has not been created.
I want

I make a copy of web.xml file from another project and  add configurations I want to run the first example of struts 2 framework,since I add the Servlet Filter  fom this toturial http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-with-artifacts-in-web-inf-lib-and-use-ant-to-build-the-application.html

but this exception occur

```
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/D:/f/alaa%20college/year%204/2ed%20semester/Advance%20SW%20application/­struts/FirstStrutsTest/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.2.3.jar!
/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? How did you create the project? In Eclipse it should be as simple as creating a *Dynamic Web Project* and ensuring that you tick the *Create deployment descriptor* checkbox during one of the last steps of the project wizard (when having a Servlet 3.0 target runtime it's namely by default disabled).

Comment: I am using netbeans 9, I create the project , new ->  java web , Web application , as the way I create any jsp-servlet application.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Netbeans. Good luck with the problem.

Comment: Don't import/include unnecessary/all jar files to application's classpath.

Comment: @Ischin, I don't know what is the necessary files I have to include, with practice I may know better, thanx for advice.

Comment: @Alaa Only add the needed jar files. Include all jars will cause the web server fails to start. For instance, did you use the **struts2-gxp-plugin**?

Answer (score 1):

use java EE 5 version instead of 6 to create web.xml file automatically but I am still facing the problem in demploying struts 2 sample app without plugin

Answer (score 1):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the web.xml under /WEB-INF in your WAR file and put struts-plugin.xml in /WEB-INF/classes and try again.

Comment: where can I find struts-plugin.xml file?